# How to parse the RDF ontology (turtle file) in c# model classes

Tags: c#, rdf, graphdb, turtle-rdf

I have the ontology file. I want to write the OData services on top of my graph database. For this I need to provide the EdmModel in order to register my OData route. but it can not be done because schema is in ttl file and also in the server. According to this [blog](https://pds.blog.parliament.uk/2018/01/24/accessing-semantic-data-with-odata-web-interface/), we can create the model by fetching the schema from the server. But there [github](https://github.com/ukparliament/OData) code is having lot of issues. Is there anyone know how to convert it to the c# model classes?

My sample schema in turtle format :

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

@prefix : <http://www.example.com/schema/abc#> .

: a owl:Ontology .

# Class
:Organization a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Organization"@en ;
  skos:definition ""@en .

# Properties
:Name a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :Organization ;
  rdfs:range xsd:string .
:CreatedDate a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :Organization ;
  rdfs:range xsd:dateTime .

# Relation
:hasRole a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :Organization ;
  rdfs:range :Role .
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're after here. You have a turtle file with an ontology, and... what? Also: you're talking abut 'this blog' and 'there [their?] github code', but you haven't provided a link to either. Finally, you ask "Is there anyone know how to convert it to c# model classes" - how to convert _what_, exactly, and to _what_ c# model classes?

Comment: Sorry that I missed to put the link. Actually I want my RDF model to be converted in C# classes so that I can register the OData route by passing the EdmModel (with the help of the classes generated) to it. If you any specification pls comment. The link is : https://pds.blog.parliament.uk/2018/01/24/accessing-semantic-data-with-odata-web-interface/

Answer (score 2):

There are some translators from SPARQL to OData. I haven't tried them, but here are some links. If you search for "odata rdf" or "odata sparql", you'll find more links on Stack Exchange.

- https://github.com/BrightstarDB/odata-sparql/tree/master/ODataSparql.Server is an example exposing a bit of DBpedia 3.9 as OData

  - Driven by the data model https://github.com/BrightstarDB/odata-sparql/tree/master/ODataSparql.Server
  - which also shows you the strength of OData/EDMX (allows a lot more specific description of entities and navigation between them) and the weakness (a lot more verbose than even OWL)
  - https://www.w3.org/2013/04/odw/odw13_submission_4.pdf is a paper that describes the approach: "an OData service is driven by the underlying domain model". "we have not implemented (generation of domain model from RDFS/OWL) but we are fairly confident that some level of useable OData service metadata could be automatically generated"
  - was presented at Open Data on the Web, April 2013: https://www.w3.org/2013/04/odw/papers
- http://inova8.com/joomla/index.php/blog/odata-and-sparqlrdf-contradictory-or-complementary
- Olingo2SPARQL: An OData V2 SPARQL provider for the Apache Olingo framework.

  - https://github.com/peterjohnlawrence/inova8.olingo2sparql.
  - Odata4SPARQL: An OData V3 SPARQL server built upon the Odata4j framework.
    https://github.com/peterjohnlawrence/inova8.odata4sparql
  - Very good explanation of the strengths and weaknesses of each.
  - Seems to build upon the above "SPARQL/OData Interop proposed W3C interoperation proxy between OData and SPARQL (Kal Ahmed, 2013)". However, Kal Ahmed's position paper at ODW13 is in now way related to W3C
  - describes "Contradictions between OData and RDF/SPARQL" (i.e. impedance mismatches)
- http://data.oceandrilling.org/labs/odata.html

  - describes conversion of SPARQL results (CSV) to OData. This seems an overkill since the data is rectangular, could just use ODBC/JDBC
  - http://data.oceandrilling.org/source/usioOdata.java.html and two more source files
  - describes real case of using Tableau for complex data